# Increase height of cell in Application setting screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, application-settings

I am using this [Tutorial](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846575&seqNum=12) for developing  application setting screen.The problem is i want to increase height of cell in setting screen.And I have not taken any table view i am doing that by using Root.plist file.i.e i want to increase  height of Legal field in this  [Image](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap16_9780133028348/elementLinks/16fig09.jpg) (application setting screen not in table view of application)

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to save the selected indexPath row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   self.selectedRowIndex = [indexPath retain];
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Then, when you have the currently selected index, you can tell the tableView that it should give that row more space.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   //check if the index actually exists
   if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) 
   {
        return 100;
   }
   return 44;
}
```

This will return height 100 for the selected cell. You can also check [this](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this set row height in a UITableView

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return the height For Row.
return 100.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it can be seen from your image the indexPath for which you need to increase the row height is section 1 and row 0:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

   NSIndexPath *indexValue = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];

   if (indexValue == indexPath)
      return 100.0;
   else
      return 44.0;
}
```